# SQLexception registration form servlets

Tags: java, sqlite, servlets, sqlexception

I am creating a registration form but getting errors when i'm inserting into the database. I have created the following code:

```
        try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/bin/dbit.db");
                insertDB = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('" + username + "', '" + password + "');";

                Statement st = connection.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate(insertDB);             
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");

            } catch (SQLException e){
                System.out.println("SQLException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have a database file with the name dbit in the bin folder in the Apache folder. This database file is created with Sqliteman-1.2.2 and I got two files (dbit file 3kb and dbit.db 0kb).

I want to insert the username and password in the database but I'm getting an SQLException. In the stacktrace: SQLExcepton: no such table: users. But that table does exist in the database.

Comment: How are you so certain that the users table exists?

Comment: If I open the database in SQLiteman again under Tables I see the users table with the columns etc.

Comment: What user are you using to connect using SQLiteman? Is it different to the one used by the application?

Comment: I am using the same users

Comment: You should put your solution into an answer and accept it. That way others and the system know the problem is actually solved.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now I can answer the question (yesterday the system gave me an error message). I still have to wait till tomorrow though before I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution..

SQLiteman-1.2.2 creates two database files, one database.db and database (without extension). I used the .db file but that didn't work, then changing the line:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/bin/dbit.db");
```

to:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/bin/dbit");
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: btw Don't forget to close the resources in the `finally` block. See the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13809186/814702